# Set a Maximum Range for Face Rendering in AFrame scene

Tags: three.js, aframe

i got a Scene which loads a very large .obj File (a lot of faces), this results in low fps ...

I want to set a maximum distance from camera where faces should be rendered.

So far i only tried to use the fog component, which does not what i expected...

Anyone got a idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you can achieve this by a `THREE.PerspectiveCamera` property called `far` which determines the camera frustum far plane.

You can check it out in the [docs](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/cameras/PerspectiveCamera.far). It can be easily set it like this:

```
let scene = document.querySelector("a-scene")  
scene.camera.far = 3 // default is 1000 afaik
```

Check it out in [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gftruj/hyxeka81/2/) (move around a bit).
[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/gftruj/hyxeka81/6/) i threw it into an aframe component.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your anwser.
This seems to work for some obj Files and increase the fps a bit. :)

Comment: @ChrisRoland It may help if you split your model into smaller `.obj`s. When the objects are entirely out of the viewing frustum, they shouldn't be rendered / calculated at all.

Comment: i tried this already, i did split the obj with blender 'Split by Material' resulting in 2000 files. I am not sure if loading this amount of Files is a good option